# Setting up NHibernate Fluent for cascade action.

Tags: c#, nhibernate, sqlite

I am trying to map database structure structure through nhibernate, but all of the foreign keys come without actions (default is restrict). For example:

```
constraint FK8BB739C23BE3416E foreign key (auction_ID) references "auctions"
```

HasMany with Inverse also did not help. Perhaps I missed something basic in mappings. Here is the right sqlite structure:

```
CREATE TABLE auctions (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    auction_name TEXT NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE tasks (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    task_name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE task_searchstrings (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    searchstring TEXT,
    task_ID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (task_ID)
        REFERENCES tasks(ID)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE task_auctions (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    auction_ID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    searchstring_ID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (auction_ID)
        REFERENCES auctions(ID)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (searchstring_ID)
        REFERENCES task_searchstrings(ID)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_task_auctions ON task_auctions (auction_ID, searchstring_ID);
```

Code for map classes:

```
public class auctions
{
    public virtual UInt32 ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string auction_name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<task_auctions> TaskAuctions { get; set; }
}

public class task_auctions
{
    public virtual UInt32 ID { get; set; }
    public virtual UInt32 auction_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual UInt32 searchstring_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual auctions Auction { get; set; }
    public virtual task_searchstrings TaskSearchstring { get; set; }
}

public class task_searchstrings
{
    public virtual UInt32 ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string searchstring { get; set; }
    public virtual UInt32 task_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual tasks Task { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<task_auctions> TaskAuctions { get; set; } 
}

public class tasks
{
    public virtual UInt32 ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string task_name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<task_searchstrings> TaskSearchstrings { get; set; } 
}
```

And my mappings:

```
class auctionsMap : ClassMap<auctions>
{
    public auctionsMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Assigned().Not.Nullable();
        LazyLoad();
        Map(x => x.auction_name).Not.Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.TaskAuctions).KeyColumn("auction_ID").Cascade.All();
    }
}

class task_auctionsMap : ClassMap<task_auctions>
{
    public task_auctionsMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Assigned().Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.auction_ID).Not.Nullable().UniqueKey("unique_task_auctions");
        Map(x => x.searchstring_ID).Not.Nullable().UniqueKey("unique_task_auctions");
        References(x => x.Auction, "auction_ID").Not.Insert().Not.Update();
        References(x => x.TaskSearchstring, "searching_ID").Not.Insert().Not.Update();
    }
}

class task_searchstringsMap : ClassMap<task_searchstrings>
{
    public task_searchstringsMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Assigned().Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.searchstring);
        Map(x => x.task_ID).Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.Task, "task_ID").Not.Insert().Not.Update();
        HasMany(x => x.TaskAuctions).KeyColumn("searching_ID");
    }
}

class tasksMap : ClassMap<tasks>
{
    public tasksMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Assigned().Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.task_name).Not.Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.TaskSearchstrings).KeyColumn("task_ID").Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want **database level** "on delete cascade" action you should add **ForeignKeyCascadeOnDelete** to your mapping.

```
HasMany(x => x.TaskAuctions).KeyColumn("auction_ID").ForeignKeyCascadeOnDelete()
```

You could also use NHibernate cascades:

```
HasMany(x => x.TaskAuctions).KeyColumn("auction_ID").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
```

This way, if you delete object in your application (through NHibernate ISession.Delete()), NHibernate will issue delete statements for objects in child collection. You can visit [NHibernate Cascades](http://ayende.com/blog/1890/nhibernate-cascades-the-different-between-all-all-delete-orphans-and-save-update) to get detailed info about NHiberate cascades.